# How to hyphenate text?

Tags: java, itext

I generate an PDF file with iText in Java.
My table columns have fixed widths and text, which is too long for one line is wrapped in the cell.
But hyphenation is not used. The word "Leistungsscheinziffer" is shown as:
Leistungssc //Break here
heinziffer

My code where I use hyphenation:

```
final PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(sumCols);
table.getDefaultCell().setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
table.getDefaultCell().setPadding(4f);
table.setWidths(widthsCols);
table.setWidthPercentage(100);
table.setSpacingBefore(0);
table.setSpacingAfter(5);

final Phrase result = new Phrase(text, font);
result.setHyphenation(new HyphenationAuto("de", "DE", 2,2));
final PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(table.getDefaultCell());
cell.setPhrase(result);
table.addCell(cell);
...
```

Hyphen is activated and the following test results "Lei-stungs-schein-zif-fer
"

```
Hyphenator h = new Hyphenator("de", "DE", 2, 2);
Hyphenation s = h.hyphenate("Leistungsscheinziffer"); 
System.out.println(s);
```

Is there anything I forgot to set to the table that hyphen is working there?
Thanks for your help. If you need more information about my code, I will tell you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First a remark that is irrelevant to the problem: you create a `PdfPCell` object, but you don't use it. You add the phrase to the table instead of using the `cell` object.

Now for your question: normally hyphenation is set on the `Chunk` level:

```
Chunk chunk = new Chunk("Leistungsscheinziffer");
chunk.setHyphenation(new HyphenationAuto("de", "DE", 2,2));
table.addCell(new Phrase(chunk));
```

If you want to set the hyphenation on the `Phrase` level, you can do so, but this will only work for all subsequent `Chunk`s that are added. It won't work for the content that is already stored inside the `Phrase`. In other words: you need to create an empty `Phrase` object and then add one or more `Chunk` objects:

```
Phrase phrase = new Phrase();
phrase.setHyphenation(new HyphenationAuto("de", "DE", 2,2));
phrase.add(new Chunk("Leistungsscheinziffer"));
```

I've made an example based on your code ([HyphenationExample](https://itextpdf.com/sandbox/tables/HyphenationExample)); the word "Leistungsscheinziffer" is hyphenated in the resulting PDF: [hyphenation_table.pdf](https://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/hyphenation_table.pdf).

Comment: It was a typing error ;-) I use the cell. Thanks so much for your help. I thought it would be easy to solve my problem :-D

Comment: @Bruno i'm trying to use your example but it does not hypenate the word... here is what i have please take a second and try it (im totally stuck here) https://www.dropbox.com/s/wu259ggbebb739f/itext.7z?dl=0

Comment: @vach Did you add the hyphenation jar to your CLASSPATH? You can find this jar [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itext/files/extrajars/extrajars-2.3.zip/download).