# Itext hyphenation in Table cells

Tags: java, pdf, itext, hyphenation

I´m creating a table using iText.
But the output looks really bad, because of the hyphenation, which seems not to be done properly.
I allready read this question [How to hyphenate text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20119709/itext-hyphen-in-table-cell)
and this example http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/tables/HyphenationExample
I tried the example in eclipse after i added the itext_hyph_xml.jar to my class path. No error is thrown when i run the code, but the lines

```
Hyphenator h = new Hyphenator("de", "DE", 2, 2);
Hyphenation s = h.hyphenate("Leistungsscheinziffer");
System.out.println(s);
```

print null to the console instead of "Lei-stungs-schein-zif-fer" or something similar as i expected.
I tried playing with the parameters in

```
chunk.setHyphenation(new HyphenationAuto("de", "DE", 2,2));
```

but the output in the document never differes even slightly.

The code i´m trying to get to work looks kind of like this by the way:

```
for(String s: interest){
        Chunk chunk = new Chunk(s,FONT[0]);
        chunk.setHyphenation(new HyphenationAuto("de", "DE", 2,3));
        table.addCell(new Phrase(chunk));
```

}

Comment: I just noticed, that when i updated iText no new itext_html_xml.jar was shipped. The XmlWorker had problems working with older itext versions. Might this be a problem with hyphernation aswell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured it out on my own now.
And because i couldn´t find the answer on the internet i thought i will share it here so anyone who might have the same error in the future wouldn´t need a week to figure it out.
It seems that in the class `Hyphenator` the defaultHyphLocation is set like this:

```
private static final String defaultHyphLocation = "com/itextpdf/text/pdf/hyphenation/hyph/";
```

But the structure of itext_hyph.jar looks like this:
`com.lowagie.text.pdf.hyphenation.hyph`
Obviously loading a hyph file from the jar will surely fail, since the path used by `Hyphenator` can not be found. I actually thought this would cause an error but it seems simply `null` is returned when the loading of the hyph file fails.
Calling `Hyphenator.setHyphenDir("com/lowagie/text/pdf/hyphenation/hyph/");` 
however  wouldn´t change a thing as one would think, since it changes the wrong string variable.
The only thing i could think of to solve this problem was to recreate the itext_hyph.jar according to the path given in `Hyphenator` and that acctually fixed it. Hyphenation is now working.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the right hyph.jar file ? When I inspect the files from Maven Central ( http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.itextpdf/itext-hyph-xml ), I find that both available jars have a path of com.itextpdf...